# Does VSTS pricing impacts if same users are added in multiple project collections?

Tags: azure-devops

I am planning to create multiple project collections in VSTS to organize my company projects regionally, in many case there would be set of people who will have access to multiple project collections, will it impact pricing being same user added in more than one project collection? will it consider two distinct users for billing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding a VSTS instance, there is just a team project collection.

Regarding an account with multiple VSTS instances, they are Independent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Just to clarify my understanding, if i add myself into two team Project collections associated with one Azure Subscription, My organization will be billed for 2 users right?

Comment: @LaxmikantPatil Yes, the billing is just for vsts instance.

Comment: Thanks, this helps ! I was trying for this structure since my organization has 100s of projects which we will be migrating to VSTS from on premise TFS, i am worried i should not touch the boundaries of VSTS account project count limit.